# Python Context Wrap all into Function

Tags: python

Lets say i have a following wrapper:

```
with MyWrapper():
   func_a()
   number = 123
   func_b()
```

Would it be possible to wrap everything inside the context into a single function ?

My final goal is, we currently have something simillar like:

```
run_transaction(func_a)
number = 123  # not transactional
run_transaction(func_b)
```

So my goal was to make something like with Transaction() to wrap those function calls. So in the end, the goal would be creating a func_c wrapping everything inside the context, and running it as transaction.

Is that possible ? Couldnt think of anything for it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at [decorators](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html), from what I think I've understood it could be very useful

Comment: Depending on where the functions are defined, the context can replace them. See context_lib.redirect_stdout as an example. Ideally though, func_a and func_b do not modify an ambient object (like a global database handle) but receive an input to modify - you can buffer and commit/reject changes to this in a context.

Comment: In decorators, I run on other problem.

MyFuncTransaction()[GetSomething]

That something is a wrapper to access DB thus needs a transaction as well, Couldn't figure out if I can wrap all that up in a decorator for MyFuncTransaction